# Set a Environment Variable with another environment variable inside (Postman / Test Script)

Tags: javascript, variables, environment-variables, postman

Having a hard time Setting a Environment Variable in Postman which contains another already stored environment variable.

Currently, in my Pre-Request Script I've created and set a Environment variable called `random_number`.

Pre-Request Script:

```
const num = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomInt}}") * 5 + 1;
pm.environment.set("random_number", num);
```

I know this works because I can view it on the `console.log` w/ the following code:

```
console.log(pm.variables.get('random_number'));

---> 3731
```

However, when I try Creating a new Environment variable with the following code (and with many different variations) I receive a `TypeError`:

Version 1:

```
pm.variable.get('random_number')
pm.environment.set("newpw", "NewPW " + random_number +" !");

console.log(pm.variables.get("newpw"));
```

Version 2:

```
pm.variable.get('random_number')
pm.environment.set("newpw", (NewPW{{random_number}}!));

console.log(pm.variables.get("newpw"));
```

Version 3:

```
pm.variable.get('random_number')
pm.environment.set("newpw", "NewPW " {{random_number}} " !");

console.log(pm.variables.get("newpw"));
```

Most of the time the TypeError I'm receiving has something to do with the `.get` but I'm sure I'm not formatting/setting the environment variable that includes there 1st variable `('random_number')` correctly.

Comment: You keep flipping between `variable` and `variables` in the same script. The correct syntax is `pm.variables.*`.